# Strict inequality in Fatous lemma and convergence of $f_{n}$ pointwise.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I got how the strict inequality occurs in Fatous lemma but why the limit of the characteristic function $\chi_{(n,n+1)} \rightarrow 0$ pointwise, for $E =\mathbb{R}$ , 
what happens here when $E =[0,1)$?

How to think about the limit of the function goes to 0 for each value of x?
[image]

Comment: When $E=[0,1)$, $\chi=1$ on $[0,1)$ and zero everywhere else... is that part of what you were asking?

Comment: Actually in order to understand both examples of how they are going pointwise to 0 , i took the second example as it is easy i think , so that if second is understood , i can apply it to understand first,.... i am looking at 2nd example...

Comment: Gotcha. Answer coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, $g_n=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$, so the integral of $g_n$ always equals $1$, since $g_n$ is defined to be $1$ for an interval of length $1$ and zero elsewhere. However, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we may find an $N_x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $g_n(x)=0$, which is why we can say that $g_n\to 0$ pointwise. So the integral of the pointwise limit is $0$, yet the integral of $g_n$ for all $n$ is $1$. (Note, all integrals are over all of $\mathbb{R}$.)

Does this help?

Comment: I am unable to visualize how $g_{n} \rightarrow 0$ pointwise ?? any help!!

Comment: $g_{n}$ gives either 0 or 1 , but how it converges pointwise to 0?

Comment: What is the definition of pointwise convergence you have?

Comment: First we fix f and then through a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ show that $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ for each x .. is this correct?

Comment: $f_{n}:X \rightarrow R$ ,is said to converge point wise to $f$ , if $\{f_
{n}(x )\}$ converges to $f(x)$ for each value of $x \in X$...now??

Comment: Yes. Pick any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. For large enough $n$, $f(x)=0$ and remains zero for all $n$. That is pointwise convergence to zero.

Comment: as $n \rightarrow \infty , g_{n} = \chi_{(\infty , \infty+1)}$ , then ??.. i know we cant write like that but ...

Comment: i think if you pause and look at it for a moment, you'll see what i mean. you are right that we can't write it like that, because there is no such interval.